# make x in a cell equal 8 and total

Tags: xlsx

I need an excel formula that will look at the cell and if it contains an x will treat it as a 8 and add it to the total at the bottom of the table. I have done these in the pass and I am so rusty that I cannot remember how I did it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I try and break this sort of problem into steps.  In this case, that'd be:

1. Determine if a cell is 'x' or not, and create new value accordingly.
2. Add up the new values.

If your values are in column A (for example), in column B, fill in:
`=if(A1="x", 8, 0)`  (or in R1C1 mode, `=if(RC[-1]="x", 8, 0`).

Then just sum those values (eg `sum(B1:B3)`) for your total.

```
     A    |    B
+---------+---------+
|  VALUES |  TEMP   |
+---------+---------+        
|    0    |    0  <------ '=if(A1="x", 8, 0)'
|    x    |    8    |
|  fish   |    0    |
+---------+---------+
|  TOTAL  |    8  <------ '=sum(B1:B3)'
+---------+---------+
```

If you want to be tidy, you could also hide the column with your intermediate values in.

(I should add that the way your question is worded, it almost sounds like you want to 'push' a value into the total; as far as I've ever known, you can really only 'pull' values into a total.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for total sum:

```
=SUMIF(<range you want to sum>, "<>" & <x>, <range you want to sum>)+ <x> * COUNTIF(<range you want to sum>, <x>)
```